# Using jQuery DataTables with Rollup.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, rollupjs

Ok I'm using the tool rollup for the first time and I love how small it is making the code. Tree shaking is great. However, I'm having some trouble getting it to include everything correctly. I tried having a single entry point, exp.js, where I export things from various files like this:

```
export {
    dashboardCharts
} from './dashboard.js';
```

my rollup.config.js looks like

```
export default {
    // tell rollup our main entry point
    input: [
        'assets/js/exp.js',
    ],

    output: {
      name: 'helloworld',
      file: 'build/js/main.js',
        format: 'iife'
        // format: 'umd'
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve({
            // pass custom options to the resolve plugin
            customResolveOptions: {
              moduleDirectory: 'node_modules'
            }
        }),
        multiEntry()
        // terser(),
    ],
};
```

The file dashboard.js includes the datatables library, so datatables gets included in the bundle main.js. However, datatables tests whether it should take the commonjs path or not by testing

```
else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = function (root, $) {
```

and I'm trying to execute this in the browser, so I don't want the commonjs path. Rollup's top level scope is declared like

```
var helloworld = (function (exports) {
```

so exports ends up being an empty object, the browser tries to execute the commonjs path and we get a "module is not defined" error.

I feel like I'm really close, but I'm missing a simple solution here. I also tried doing a umd format instead of iife, but it didn't help. Is there a different version of datatables I should be using?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the commonjs rollup plugin? It could be possible that datatables will short circuit this as well but might be worth a try: https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs

Answer (score 1):

I used rollup with svelte and I had some jquery legacy to import; here is how I did it:

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        json(),
        svelte({
            // Enables run-time checks when not in production.
            dev: !production,

            // Extracts any component CSS out into a separate file — better for performance.
            css: css => css.write('public/build/bundle.css'),

            // Emit CSS as "files" for other plugins to process
            emitCss: true,

            preprocess: autoPreprocess()
        }),

        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/')
        }),
        commonjs(),

        postcss({
            extract: true,
            minimize: true,
            use: [
                ['sass', {
                includePaths: [
                    './src/theme',
                    './node_modules'
                ]
                }]
            ]
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watches the `public` directory and refresh the browser on changes when not in production.
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // Minify for production.
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Maybe is too much what I posted (I wanted to show you the context from a working config), but you can extract from it the needed part.
I think you need the `commonjs` plugin.